# How can i iterate a loop to select if there are multiple strings

Tags: java, arrays, loops

If `string[] a =[a1,b1,c1]`, `string[] b =[a2,b2,c2]` and `string[] c = [a3,b3,c3]`, how can I iterate a loop to select a1, a2, a3 and b1, b2, b3 and c1, c2, c3  and print using Java

To iterate over one string:

```java
String[] allAs = AN.split(",");
        
for (String aANo : allAs) {
    System.out.println(aANo)
}
```

Can anyone help? If there are three or more string then how to do this?

Comment: Are they always in the correct order and have the same length?

Comment: They always in the correct order but the length can be varied.

Comment: Then how do you identify the matches? Are matches always starting with the same characters?

Comment: Matching can be done by index.

Comment: Not if they have different length. And even if they are ordered, what if you have : `string[] a =[a1,b1]` and `string[] b =[a2,b2,c2]` and `string[] c = [a3,c3]`? No index matching possible

Comment: You need to provide a complete example, with the expected output

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the arrays all have the same length. I also used a list to add all the arrays cause i thought you might have more arrays. What you actually need is a for loop on indexes that is what I do.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] a = new String[]{"a", "b", "c"};
    String[] b = new String[]{"g", "f", "e"};
    String[] c = new String[]{"n", "m", "c"};

    List<String[]> allArrays = new ArrayList<>();
    allArrays.add(a);
    allArrays.add(b);
    allArrays.add(c);

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        String concatString = "";
        for (String[] array : allArrays) {
            concatString = concatString.concat(array[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(concatString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Arrays don't have the same length as stated in comments

Answer (score 0):

Updated my answer...

```
    List<String[]> stringList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
stringList.add(a);
stringList.add(b);
stringList.add(c);

for(String [] array : stringList){
for(String word : array){
System.out.println(word + " , ");
}
}
```

Comment: Arrays don't have the same length as stated in comments

Comment: Sorry I haven't seen that, so actually we have to do the exact stuff with arrays of different sizes. Am I right???

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I just updated my answer. It works for arrays of any length. Feel free to report any bug in it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments & question, it looks like you have varied length array & so in that case, something like below may be suitable:

```
        String a[] = { "A", "A1", "A2" };
        String b[] = { "B", "B1" };
        String c[] = { "C", "C1", "C3" };
        String aa = "";
        String bb = "";
        String cc = "";
        int length = Math.max(c.length, Math.max(a.length, b.length));
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            aa = a.length < (i + 1) ? "" : a[i]+",";
            bb = b.length < (i + 1) ? "" : b[i]+",";
            cc = c.length < (i + 1) ? "" : c[i];
            System.out.println(aa + bb+ cc);

        }
```

Output:

```
A,B,C
A1,B1,C1
A2,C3
```

Comment: Your input is wrong. Each array seems to have X elements, which have the same number, but different prefix `String[] a =[a1,b1,c1]`. You have same prefix and different suffix

Comment: Yeah, but l guess logic remains same even if input is different.

Comment: 1. It changes, as you have to access the indexes differently. 2. Your result is wrong as well. The result should be `A, A1, A2` in a single line, not in 3 different lines

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by order and dynamic length of each array.

```
String s = Arrays.toString(a)+Arrays.toString(b)+Arrays.toString(c);
s = s.replaceAll("]\\[",", ");
s = s.substring(1,s.length()-1);
System.out.println(s);
```

Enjoy mate.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer That's right.

Comment: Wrong result `a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, c3, c2` for input `a = new String[] { "a1", "b1" }; b = new String[] { "a2", "b2", "c2" }; c = new String[] { "a3", "c3" };`. It is in the wrong order

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Works perfectly and way shorter.
Would like to see if you can find a shorter solution for that...